# How to start a service upon the output of a command?

Tags: systemd

I would like to start a specific service after another one has **completely** started. Specifically, I need an OpenVPN service to be up and have completed its startup to start another service.

I would normally use `After=` but it does not work as intended with OpenVPN, which informs that it has started right after launch and before its setup is completed.

A solution to this would be to constrain the start of my service to the output or exit status of a script<sup>(*)</sup> (or to the existence of a file which would be crated by the said script).

**Is this possible with systemd?**

---

<sup>(*)</sup> The script would ping a host known to be accessible only via the VPN tunnel and exit once connectivity is achieved (or drop a file)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388586/systemd-requires-vs-wants

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the service unit with

```
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
```

and make the last script (or a child of that) which is started by OpenVPN during initialization (wait for the desired logging output and then) call `systemd-notify`.