# Why does systemd randomly fail to mount a remote NFS directory?

Tags: systemd, mount, nfs

Ubuntu 20.04.  I have a `systemd` mount file that mounts a remote NFS path.  The mount file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=/userdata
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Mount]
What=10.20.30.40:/data/users
Where=/userdata
Type=nfs
Options=nofail,rw,soft,intr,actimeo=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Randomly, the path will fail to mount on reboot.  It is enabled.  If I start in manually, it works fine and mounts the `/userdata/` directory.

Checking the status of the mount file gives a "Network is unreachable" error:

```
$ sudo systemctl status userdata.mount
● userdata.mount - /userdata
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/userdata.mount; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-06-07 09:56:27 EDT; 6h ago
      Where: /userdata
       What: 10.20.30.40:/data/users

Jun 07 09:56:27 hostname mount[474]: mount.nfs: Network is unreachable
Jun 07 09:56:27 hostname systemd[1]: userdata.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Jun 07 09:56:27 hostname systemd[1]: userdata.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 07 09:56:27 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to mount /userdata.
Warning: journal has been rotated since unit was started, output may be incomplete.
```

From web searches, this is a common problem.  It predates `systemd`, though, so the most common solution is "write a `systemd` mount file for it."  In this case, I'm already using `systemd`, so that doesn't help.

I found an [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NFS/Troubleshooting#mount.nfs4:_Network_is_unreachable) comment that suggest I should enable `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` to solve this problem.  However, the command `$ sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` shows that this unit file is already enabled on my system.

So, I don't know what else to do.  How do I get this path to mount consistently at startup?

**Edit**

I tried replacing `Wants=network-online.target` with `Requires=network-online.target`, but this did not fix or otherwise affect the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is `Wants=network-online.target` instead of `Requires=network-online.target`.

While `Wants=` asks for `network-online.target` to be started, it may ignore a failure in `network-online.target`. However, for an NFS this obviously is essential. `Requires=` strictly requests successful starts and running services. I think your network is a bit unstable during boot.

See [Wants= vs. Requires= in systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388881/123460)

Comment: That's a good idea, but it didn't work, unfortunately.  After making that change, the directory still failed to mount on the second test reboot.